# Is it correct to say "We have a 3-day holiday" in British English?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

I know that British people say "**holiday**" and American say "**vacation**".

But the confusing part is how they are used as **countable and uncountable nouns**.

Say, you don't have to go to work on Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday because your country is celebrating an important event.

I am sure we can say "**We have a 3-day vacation**".

But I don't think we say "**We have a 3-day holiday**"

I guess we might say "**we have 3 holidays**".

Is it correct to say "**We have a 3-day holiday**" in British English?

Comment: In Britain, we have statutory holidays called 'bank holidays', and at Easter we have the Friday before Easter ('Good Friday') and the Monday after Easter ('Easter Monday'), so that is a weekend with **two bank holidays**.

Comment: When there is a national holiday, we don't say vacation in AmE or BrE. We have **a three-day weekend** or a **long weekend**  because **Friday or Monday is a holiday**. I don't bother trying to enter an answer with these questions because you never seem to close out any questions.

Comment: We have a convention that numbers smaller than some limit (often 11) are written as words, so yes, if three consecutive weekdays are official holidays (but that would never happen in the UK), we can say 'we have a **three-day** holiday', or a three-day break, or three days off. Generally a (mostly American) vacation is a trip away, not just a break from work.

Comment: Your "we have three holidays" means three *distinct* holidays, each of which might be one day or many days.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's fine to say a three-day holiday.

Brits don't use the word vacation at all. That's an entirely American construct. [We understand it, but it's still an imported word we never would actually use.] We have no definition other than context to differentiate 'time away on a Greek beach' from 'a few days off work, but still at home'.
AmE is simpler in this respect, if you're going away it's a vacation. If it's just time off work, it's a holiday. Some of the newspapers in the UK are trying to persuade us that 'staycation' could be a word for time off, staying at home, but I'm not convinced yet.

So, 'a three-day holiday' is just fine, as is a 'three-day weekend' if the Friday or Monday is a holiday. Any finer distinctions, such as which days, will have to be provided as further information/clarification.

Comment: A three-day holiday is not a three-day weekend. I went to Paris on a three-day holiday. [I took three days off work.].

Comment: I didn't say a three-day holiday was *the same as* a three-day weekend. I merely said both are acceptable terms.

Comment: I think one needs to explain it, though. That is, it does not involve any officially declared holiday.

Comment: In UK the term 'vacation' is sometimes used to refer to school holidays (the period between each term). Also 'staycation' is used to refer to a holiday where you don't go abroad (not specifically at home).

Comment: @WeatherVane - Never heard it used that way in my entire life… though it's been a while since I was last a school. Used that way would actually break its meaning as inherited from the US, where it means 'on a Greek beach' rather than at home.

Comment: [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/the-school-or-university-year) gives this, and so does [A Guide to University Holidays](https://thinkstudent.co.uk/a-guide-to-university-holidays/)

Comment: Yes, UK universities used it even when I was a student 50 years ago. But no-one calls a public holiday a vacation.

Comment: As I never went to university, I can't comment on that ;))

Comment: In England, the legal year for the High Court, Court of Appeal,  and Supreme Court is divided into four terms: Michaelmas (October to December), Hilary (January to April), Easter( April to May), and Trinity (June to July). Between terms, those courts are **in vacation**, and no trials or appeals are heard in them.

Comment: Not circles I tend to hang out in. I'll bet 95% of Brits don't know this usage exists.

Comment: There is also the meaning of vacation given in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacation) **4** : an act or an instance of [vacating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacating). "Q. When is your vacation?" "A. The bailiffs are coming tomorrow!"

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - considering that just about everybody seems to go to 'uni' (yuk!) these days, I wouldn't bet on that.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that in the UK, [nearly all national holidays are deliberately placed on a Monday](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays) (the exceptions being Christmas, Boxing Day, New Year's Day and Good Friday). So, if you exclude the Christmas to New Year period, all bank holidays extend the weekend to be a 3 (or, during Easter, 4) day weekend. Because of this, the typical phrasing is either "three day weekend" or "bank holiday weekend".

In your example you ask what it would be called if the country didn't have to go to work on the Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday of a week - it is very unlikely that the government would approve that - but if that was the case then a "three day holiday" or a "5 day weekend" is probably how it would be phrased.

Comment: Good Friday is handily adjacent to a weekend. In 2022 the UK Early Spring Bank Holiday was moved from the first Monday in May to Thursday 2 June to add to the extra Bank Holiday (3 June) for the queen's platinum jubilee, so making a four-day weekend.